# What is this form/input called?

Tags: html, forms

What is this form/input called?

[image]

Comment: It's not a single control. Go find a site that has it. Look at the HTML.

Comment: i tried many keywords, but none of them show what i want :(

Comment: "list view" and "move button"

Comment: FWIW, Telerik calls it a ["Transfer ListBox"](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/functionality/transfer/defaultcs.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I have seen it called a [`list box`](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-move-items-between-listbox-using.html).
2. Microsoft has a desktop version called [`list builder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511484.aspx#listBuilders)
3. Rich-faces called it a `listShuttle` in 3.x and now its called a [`pickList`](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=pickList)

So I dont think there is a standard "name for it." Maybe [`List Builder`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_builder) is correct since Wikipedia is the one true reference...